# Ruby on Rails 4.2.2 ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've recently cleaned out all of my gems due to this issue and tried to reinstall via the following:

```
$ gem install rails
$ rails new myproject
$ cd myproject
$ rails server
```

While the above seems pretty straightforward for a new rails installs, I got the following 500 error:

```
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run 'rails server -h' for more startup option'
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-06-18 16:44:22] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-06-18 16:44:22] INFO  ruby 2.2.0 (2014-12-25) [x86_64-darwin14]
[2015-06-18 16:44:22] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=60434 port=3000


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 16:44:27 -0400

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:338:in 'parse_query'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/request.rb:191:in 'GET'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:300:in 'GET'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:14:in 'parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_parameters.rb:37:in 'filtered_parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in 'process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in 'process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in 'process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in 'process'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in 'process'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in 'dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in 'dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in 'block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in 'call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in 'dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in 'serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in 'block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in 'each'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in 'serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in 'call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in 'call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in 'call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in 'call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in 'call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in 'call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in 'context'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in 'call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in 'call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in 'call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in 'call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in 'call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in 'block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in 'call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in '_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in '_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in 'run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in 'call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in 'call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in 'call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in 'call'
  web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in 'call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in 'call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in 'call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in 'block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in 'block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in 'tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in 'tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in 'call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in 'call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in 'call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in 'call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in 'call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in 'call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in 'call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in 'call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in 'call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in 'call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in 'call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in 'call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in 'service'
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in 'service'
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in 'run'
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in 'block in start_thread'
```

What am-I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log mentions version 1.6.3 of rack. Try adding `gem 'rack', '1.6.2'` to your Gemfile and running `bundle update rack` from the command line. Restart your server. That seems to work, for now.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I couldn't find a match with the fix. The answer provided is much appreciated!

Comment: I was able to fix this using 1.5.5